# Spark Scala: Querying same table multiple times

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, processing-efficiency

I am trying to query multiple columns from the same table (bigTable) to generate some aggregated columns (column1_sum, column2_sum, column3_count). In the end, I join all the columns together to form one table.

**Code below**

```
val t1 = bigTable
            .filter($"column10" === value1)
            .groupBy("key1","key2")
            .agg(sum("column1") as "column1_sum")

val t2 = bigTable
            .filter($"column11"===1)
            .filter($"column10" === value1)
            .groupBy("key1","key2")
            .agg(sum("column2") as "column2_sum")

val t3 = bigTable
            .filter($"column10" === value3)
            .groupBy("key1","key2")
            .agg(countDistinct("column3") as "column3_count")

tAll
            .join(t1,Seq("key1","key2"),"left_outer")
            .join(t2,Seq("key1","key2"),"left_outer")
            .join(t3,Seq("key1","key2"),"left_outer")
```

**Issues with the above code**

bigTable is a huge table (it runs into millions of rows). So, querying it multiple times is not efficient. The query is taking a lot of time to run.

Any ideas on how I could achieve the same output in a more efficient way? Is there a way to query the bigTable lesser number of times?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: you can `cache` intermediate RDDs/DataSets/DataFrames - eg `val intermediate = bigTable.filter($"column10" === value1).cache` - then `intermediate` can be reused when building t1 and t2 - you can `unpersist` intermediate when you are finished with it - spark caching holds the results in distributed memory to improve preformance

Comment: I thought about it but in this case, the intermediate table would also be huge. Also, each time my filters are also different. Any other ideas on what I could do?

Comment: I'm afraid the issue is how much resource you are willing to throw at this. If you build a Spark cluster with enough infrastructure then huge is a entirely relative.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Cacheing also makes sense. I will try to do that wherever it makes sense. Thanks @PJFanning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest improvement is to perform only as single aggregation, where predicated is pushed into `CASE ... WHEN ...` block, and replace `countDistinct` with an approximate equivalent

```
tAll
  .groupBy("key1","key2")
  .agg(
    sum(
      when($"column10" === "value1", $"column1")
    ).as("column1_sum"),
    sum(
      when($"column10" === "value1" and $"column11" === 1, $"column2")
    ).as("column2_sum"),
    approx_count_distinct(
      when($"column10" === "value3", $"column3")
    ).as("column3_count"))
  .join(tAll, Seq("key1", "key2"), "right_outer"))
```

Depending on the functions used and the a prori knowledge about data distribution you can also try to replace aggregation with window functions with similar `CASE ... WHEN ...` logic

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window
 .partitionBy("key1", "key2")
 .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

tAll
  .withColumn(
    "column1_sum", 
    sum(when($"column10" === "value1", $"column1")).over(w))
 ...
```

but it is often a less stable approach.

You should also consider bucketing `bigTable` using grouping columns:

```
val n: Int = ???  // Number of buckets
bigTable.write.bucketBy(n, "key1", "key2").saveAsTable("big_table_clustered")

val bigTableClustered = spark.table("big_table_clustered")
```

Comment: Thanks @user6910411. I will definitely try the approaches you mentioned. I agree, bucketing would be very helpful in my case and it would make the query run fast.

Answer (score 1):

One of the major improvements to my code would be to query the bigTable once, as opposed to multiple times as mentioned in the question.

A piece of code that I am trying out (my code is similar , this is just an illustration):

```
bigTable
    .filter($"column10" === value1)
    .groupBy("key1", "key2")
    .agg(
      sum("column1") as "column1_sum",
      sum("column2") as "column2_sum",
      countDistinct(when($"column11"===1, col("column3"))) as "column3_count"
)
```